# Running code on page loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC view that contains some dropdowns like this :

```
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CS.C1, Model.CS.Category1List, "-- Välj kategori --")%>
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CS.C2, Model.CS.Category2List, "-- Välj kategori --")%>
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CS.C3, Model.CS.Category3List, "-- Välj kategori --")%>
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CS.C4, Model.CS.Category4List, "-- Välj kategori --")%>
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CS.C5, Model.CS.Category5List, "-- Välj kategori --")%>
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CS.C6, Model.CS.Category6List, "-- Välj kategori --")%>
```

To compliment this with AJAX calls (to create CascadingDropDown) I have the following javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#CS_C1").change(function () { lastCategoryId = $("#CS_C1").val() });
            $("#CS_C2").change(function () { lastCategoryId = $("#CS_C2").val() });
            $("#CS_C3").change(function () { lastCategoryId = $("#CS_C3").val() });
            $("#CS_C4").change(function () { lastCategoryId = $("#CS_C4").val() });
            $("#CS_C5").change(function () { lastCategoryId = $("#CS_C5").val() });
            $("#CS_C6").change(function () { lastCategoryId = $("#CS_C6").val() });

            $("#CS_C2").CascadingDropDownCategory("#CS_C1", '/AdCategory/GetCategoriesByParent', '', true, SetFilter);
            $("#CS_C3").CascadingDropDownCategory("#CS_C2", '/AdCategory/GetCategoriesByParent', '', true, SetFilter);
            $("#CS_C4").CascadingDropDownCategory("#CS_C3", '/AdCategory/GetCategoriesByParent', '', true, SetFilter);
            $("#CS_C5").CascadingDropDownCategory("#CS_C4", '/AdCategory/GetCategoriesByParent', '', true, SetFilter);
            $("#CS_C6").CascadingDropDownCategory("#CS_C5", '/AdCategory/GetCategoriesByParent', '', true, SetFilter);

            $("#LS_L2").CascadingDropDown("#LS_L1", '/Location/GetLocationsByParent', '', true);

            alert(lastCategoryId);
            SetFilter(lastCategoryId);
        });
```

The CascadingDropDownCategory function is from [this site](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/20/cascadingdropdown-jquery-plugin-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

When doing a post the dropdowns is set properply but when running

```
SetFilter(lastCategoryId);
```

The lastCategoryId is sill -1? I can see that the dropdowns have got values and should also have triggered the change event? Why is i getting -1? How could I solve it?

BestRegards

Comment: There's this thing called a loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastCategoryId` is set in the `.change()` callback (which means it won't get set until the `<select>` changes), so by the end you get to the end of your document ready function it won't be set yet.

Also, whenever you declare a variable without `var`, it becomes global. Always declare variables with `var` at the start of a function.

Comment: Thanks! SetFilter should thereby be set after the change event.